# " No qualifying bean of type " while DAO testing of spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have written a spring mvc web application. The application runs properly.
 I am trying to write DAO tests using spring Test suite. I am using the same config file servlet-context.xml as used by the web-app. When I run the test I get *No qualifying bean of type* error

I have looked around stackoverflow but it "appears" my configuration is right. Please suggest :-
find the code below :-

```
 package net.codejava.spring.dao;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import net.codejava.spring.model.User;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:*/servlet-context.xml")
public class UserDAOImplTests {

    @Autowired
    public UserDAO userDao;//=new UserDAOImpl();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        User user=new User();
        user.setAddedBy(1);
        user.setCreated(new Date());
        user.setEmail("imtoshi01@gmail.com");
        user.setFirstName("Toshi");
        user.setId(98);
        user.setIsSoftDeleted('N');
        user.setLastName("Singhal");
        user.setLicenseId(1);
        user.setMobile("9030137901");
        user.setPassword("password");
        user.setUpdated(new Date());
        userDao.addUser(user);
        List<User> users= userDao.findAllUsers();
        String actual=users.get(0).getFirstName();
        Assert.assertEquals("Toshi", actual);
    }

}
```

My servlet-context.xml has bean initialized. 
Servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.codejava.spring" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.codejava.spring.dao" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:sqlserver://url;" />
        <property name="username" value="admin_hs" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        <!-- <property name="hibernateProperties"> <props> <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
            </props> </property> -->
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean id="userDao" class="net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Error log : -

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: are you sure `classpath:*/servlet-context.xml` is right ? where is your servlet-context.xml ?

Comment: Component scan - <context:component-scan base-package="net.codejava.spring.dao" /> - is redundant. You can get rid of it.

Comment: could you post the `UserDAOImpl` class as well ? Also , are there any other classes which are implementing/extending the `UserDAO` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:servlet-context.xml")
public class UserDAOImplTests { ....
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a context for your test cases, load only those beans which are required. E.g. you don't need components like InternalResourceViewResolver, resource mapping for unit testing.

To achieve this, instead of loading servlet-context.xml completely for your test cases, divide servlet-context.xml into two-three smaller pieces.

And those xml files only which are required for your test cases. (As an extra work, you will need to change how you are loading the xml files for dev testing, but that's worth it.)